# Clipping several raster layers to the same exact size QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm new to QGIS, sorry if this is a newbie question... I need to clip about 40 different raster layers from one vector layer (that has the boundaries of 4 neighboring countries) but I need them all to have the same exact size, which didn't happen when I tried clipping the rasters one by one... How can I do this?

I thought about using the first cut raster to clip all others but I can't clip a raster with another raster... or can I?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I think I had to post this question to solve it... I clipped the first raster with my vector layer and used it to make a mask with either 1's ou 0's. I then multiplied this mask with every raster one by one.